# how to merge two arrays in one array based on key and values pair

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays like below example..

```
 $arr1 = array("0" => "1");
 $arr2 = array("2" => "3");
```

i want to make two different array by merging all the keys in one array and and all the values inside another array.

Expected output..

```
$arr3 = array("0" => "2");
$arr4 = array("1" => "3");
```

Comment: And what do you do if you have 3 values? What should the expected output be: `array(A => B, C => NULL)` or `array(A => B, C)`, ...?

Comment: i want to merge all the keys in one array and all the values in another array.

Comment: I think your expected output is a bit off. Take a look at `array_keys()` and `array_values()` and then use the suggested `array_combine()`

Comment: Just repeating the same thing you've already said when people ask for clarification is not helpful.

Comment: Using this lame example hardly makes any sense. You need to provide another example with more no. of array elements. At least clarify the question when people are willing to help you out instead of making no effort and expecting people to solve the entire question for you.

Comment: I removed the CakePHP tag. Please use tags that match the problem. This clearly is generic and has nothing to do with CakePHP at all!

Answer (score 0):

The following work for the example given. Use [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) with [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) for `$arr3` and [`reset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) for `$arr4` -

```
//extract the keys and combine them
$arr3 = array_combine(array_keys($arr1), array_keys($arr2));

//extract the first value and combine them
$arr4 = array_combine(array(reset($arr1)), array(reset($arr2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that, using [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [array_vals](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php):

```
<?
    $arr1 = array("0" => "1");
    $arr2 = array("2" => "3");
    $a1_keys = array_keys($arr1);
    $a1_vals = array_values($arr1);
    $a2_keys = array_keys($arr2);
    $a2_vals = array_values($arr2);
    $keys_merge = array();
    $vals_merge = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr1); $i++) {
        $keys_merge[$a1_keys[$i]] = $a2_keys[$i];
        $vals_merge[$a1_vals[$i]] = $a2_vals[$i];
    }
    print_r($keys_merge);
    print_r($vals_merge);
```

Script above assumes that You have correctly formatted arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $arr1 = array("0","1");
 $arr2 = array("2","3");

 foreach($arr1 as $key => $value){
   $arr3[$value] = $arr2[$key];
 }
```

That's what you need. 
Note: 1) your description of $arr1 and $arr2 is incorrect 
2) It needs more logic when array lengths are not equal.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you can use [array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

```
<?php
$a = array('green', 'red', 'yellow');
$b = array('avocado', 'apple', 'banana');
$c = array_combine($a, $b);

print_r($c);
?>
```

Comment: i want to merge all the keys in one array and all the values in another array.